# Django Python social auth - 'FacebookBackend' object has no attribute 'auth_allowed'

Tags: python, django, facebook

I'm using:

`python-openid==2.2.5
python-social-auth==0.2.13`

Trying to get the facebook login working and get email from it.  Facebook login works with no pipeline define, and gives the above error with this pipeline:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',  # <--- enable this one
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

Full Error

```
AttributeError at /dev-xyzzyxsford/complete/facebook/
'FacebookBackend' object has no attribute 'auth_allowed'
Request Method: GET
fRequest URL:   http://xyzzyxssdigest.com/dev-xyzzyxsford/complete/facebook/?redirect_state=uAavJwDjtf4dwEjEfdo&code=1-bJMKDW7SJxgKQH3Gb0iOUpDRz_n5Gysz2xks3mG0DjEIbi4boX9lrLTbpmiP_lUF4mfSIS4sT1P6CtNm7cS2vs67XndwEGE9osBq2znasxf6kBtC_OacPR2cQGTuW3cnnEBf1fH-MjZ7U_1NGVGMSnZbNt0yaB-LFENyol_T_I8B9_JfNgRzX1JtOui6p4NIvc4cuKFFtZZb7Gz2auCgorKNMlqjaVqnptj-xGdh7swwKm9Ab8GQM3PxPEe5IpKYYC9mKh9WONejQ&state=fUZpFHUj4jlOyuAavJwDjtf4dwEjEfdo
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'FacebookBackend' object has no attribute 'auth_allowed'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/pipeline/social_auth.py in auth_allowed, line 14
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/useruseruser/diaper',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 23 Oct 2015 17:59:33 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py in wrapped_view
                    return view_func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social_auth/decorators.py in wrapper
                        return func(request, request.social_auth_backend, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social_auth/views.py in complete
                    return complete_process(request, backend, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social_auth/views.py in complete_process
                user = auth_complete(request, backend, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social_auth/views.py in auth_complete
                return backend.auth_complete(user=user, request=request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social_auth/backends/facebook.py in auth_complete
                        return self.do_auth(access_token, expires=expires, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social_auth/backends/facebook.py in do_auth
                    return authenticate(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py in authenticate
                        user = backend.authenticate(**credentials) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social_auth/backends/__init__.py in authenticate
                    out = self.pipeline(pipeline, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social_auth/backends/__init__.py in pipeline
                            result = func(*args, **out) or {} ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/pipeline/social_auth.py in auth_allowed
                if not backend.auth_allowed(response, details): ...
▶ Local vars
Request information

GET
Variable    Value
state   
u'fUZpFHUj4jlOyuAavJwDjtf4dwEjEfdo'
code    
u'AQAKENo7d42Q_mmup1-bJMKDW7SJxgKQH3Gb0iOUpDRz_n5G-sngWk-ysz2xks3mG0DjEIbi4boX9lrLTbpmiP_lUF4mfS_KIS4sT1P6CtNm7cS2vs67XndwEGE9osBq2znasxf6kBtC_OacPR2cQGTuW3cnnEBf1fH-MjZ7U_1NGVGMSnZbNt0yaBKHvaw-ze26iTaWnbEZnMUm-LFENyol_T_I8B9_JfNgRzX1JtOui6p4NIvc4cuKFFtZZb7Gz2auCgorKNMlqjaVqnptj-xGdh7swwKm9Ab8GMOKflyt27JqjgQAmXdI311YU_QM3PxPEe5IpKYYC9mKh9WONejQ'
redirect_state  
u'fUZpFHUj4jlOyuAavJwDjtf4dwEjEfdo'
POST
No POST data
FILES
No FILES data
COOKIES
Variable    Value
csrftoken   
'dUYuBF2j6ZiefyY6T8dWwfMlj9p4qewG'
sessionid   
'dw5fycm68vdg70ef9wmemku0mjgtaag3'
__cfduid    
'd061482de3cbf077bd5e0c708fd0eda701445303131'
META
Variable    Value
wsgi.version    
(1, 0)
RUN_MAIN    
'true'
HTTP_REFERER    
'http://xyzzyxssdigest.com/dev-xyzzyxsford/'
HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY   
'US'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.0'
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6'
SCRIPT_NAME 
u''
LESSOPEN    
'| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
SSH_CLIENT  
'45.37.251.252 34864 22'
REQUEST_METHOD  
'GET'
LOGNAME 
'xasdrw'
USER    
'asdfasdas'
PATH    
'/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games'
QUERY_STRING    
'redirect_state=fUZpFHUj4jlOyuAavJwDjtf4dwEjEfdo&code=AQAKENo7d42Q_mmup1-bJMKDW7SJxgKQH3Gb0iOUpDRz_n5G-sngWk-ysz2xks3mG0DjEIbi4boX9lrLTbpmiP_lUF4mfS_KIS4sT1P6CtNm7cS2vs67XndwEGE9osBq2znasxf6kBtC_OacPR2cQGTuW3cnnEBf1fH-MjZ7U_1NGVGMSnZbNt0yaBKHvaw-ze26iTaWnbEZnMUm-LFENyol_T_I8B9_JfNgRzX1JtOui6p4NIvc4cuKFFtZZb7Gz2auCgorKNMlqjaVqnptj-xGdh7swwKm9Ab8GMOKflyt27JqjgQAmXdI311YU_QM3PxPEe5IpKYYC9mKh9WONejQ&state=fUZpFHUj4jlOyuAavJwDjtf4dwEjEfdo'
HOME    
'/home/useruseruser'
HTTP_CF_RAY 
'239f5621d21f0a00-ATL'
LANG    
'en_US.UTF-8'
TERM    
'screen'
SHELL   
'/bin/bash'
TZ  
'UTC'
HTTP_COOKIE 
'__cfduid=d061482de3cbf077bd5e0c708fd0eda701445303131; csrftoken=dUYuBF2j6ZiefyY6T8dWwfMlj9p4qewG; sessionid=dw5fycm68vdg70ef9wmemku0mjgtaag3'
SERVER_NAME 
'localhost'
REMOTE_ADDR 
'127.0.0.1'
SHLVL   
'3'
PWD 
'/home/useruseruser/diaper'
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
SERVER_PORT 
'8009'
HTTP_CF_VISITOR 
'{"scheme":"http"}'
CONTENT_LENGTH  
''
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR 
'/run/user/1000'
wsgi.file_wrapper   
''
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO  
'http, http'
CSRF_COOKIE 
u'dUYuBF2j6ZiefyY6T8dWwfMlj9p4qewG'
wsgi.input  
<socket._fileobject object at 0x7fddd368e1d0>
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36'
HTTP_HOST   
'xyzzyxssdigest.com'
wsgi.multithread    
True
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  
'1'
HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP   
'45.37.251.252'
XDG_SESSION_ID  
'6'
STY 
'13791.pts-0.linode'
_   
'/usr/bin/python'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
TERMCAP 
'SC|screen|VT 100/ANSI X3.64 virtual terminal:\\\n\t:DO=\\E[%dB:LE=\\E[%dD:RI=\\E[%dC:UP=\\E[%dA:bs:bt=\\E[Z:\\\n\t:cd=\\E[J:ce=\\E[K:cl=\\E[H\\E[J:cm=\\E[%i%d;%dH:ct=\\E[3g:\\\n\t:do=^J:nd=\\E[C:pt:rc=\\E8:rs=\\Ec:sc=\\E7:st=\\EH:up=\\EM:\\\n\t:le=^H:bl=^G:cr=^M:it#8:ho=\\E[H:nw=\\EE:ta=^I:is=\\E)0:\\\n\t:li#43:co#159:am:xn:xv:LP:sr=\\EM:al=\\E[L:AL=\\E[%dL:\\\n\t:cs=\\E[%i%d;%dr:dl=\\E[M:DL=\\E[%dM:dc=\\E[P:DC=\\E[%dP:\\\n\t:im=\\E[4h:ei=\\E[4l:mi:IC=\\E[%d@:ks=\\E[?1h\\E=:\\\n\t:ke=\\E[?1l\\E>:vi=\\E[?25l:ve=\\E[34h\\E[?25h:vs=\\E[34l:\\\n\t:ti=\\E[?1049h:te=\\E[?1049l:us=\\E[4m:ue=\\E[24m:so=\\E[3m:\\\n\t:se=\\E[23m:mb=\\E[5m:md=\\E[1m:mr=\\E[7m:me=\\E[m:ms:\\\n\t:Co#8:pa#64:AF=\\E[3%dm:AB=\\E[4%dm:op=\\E[39;49m:AX:\\\n\t:vb=\\Eg:G0:as=\\E(0:ae=\\E(B:\\\n\t:ac=\\140\\140aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~..--++,,hhII00:\\\n\t:po=\\E[5i:pf=\\E[4i:Km=\\E[M:k0=\\E[10~:k1=\\EOP:k2=\\EOQ:\\\n\t:k3=\\EOR:k4=\\EOS:k5=\\E[15~:k6=\\E[17~:k7=\\E[18~:\\\n\t:k8=\\E[19~:k9=\\E[20~:k;=\\E[21~:F1=\\E[23~:F2=\\E[24~:\\\n\t:F3=\\E[1;2P:F4=\\E[1;2Q:F5=\\E[1;2R:F6=\\E[1;2S:\\\n\t:F7=\\E[15;2~:F8=\\E[17;2~:F9=\\E[18;2~:FA=\\E[19;2~:kb=\x7f:\\\n\t:K2=\\EOE:kB=\\E[Z:kF=\\E[1;2B:kR=\\E[1;2A:*4=\\E[3;2~:\\\n\t:*7=\\E[1;2F:#2=\\E[1;2H:#3=\\E[2;2~:#4=\\E[1;2D:%c=\\E[6;2~:\\\n\t:%e=\\E[5;2~:%i=\\E[1;2C:kh=\\E[1~:@1=\\E[1~:kH=\\E[4~:\\\n\t:@7=\\E[4~:kN=\\E[6~:kP=\\E[5~:kI=\\E[2~:kD=\\E[3~:ku=\\EOA:\\\n\t:kd=\\EOB:kr=\\EOC:kl=\\EOD:km:'
LS_COLORS   
'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
LESSCLOSE   
'/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
'CGI/1.1'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR    
'45.37.251.252, 108.162.237.47'
SSH_TTY 
'/dev/pts/0'
wsgi.errors 
<open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7fdddc5b11e0>
wsgi.multiprocess   
False
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'en-US,en;q=0.8'
HTTP_X_HOST 
'xyzzyxssdigest.com'
wsgi.run_once   
False
WINDOW  
'1'
HTTP_DNT    
'1'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  
'app.settings'
CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/plain'
MAIL    
'/var/mail/useruseruser'
SSH_CONNECTION  
'45.37.251.252 34864 45.79.131.105 22'
REMOTE_HOST 
''
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip'
PATH_INFO   
u'/dev-xyzzyxsford/complete/facebook/'
Settings
Using settings module app.settings
Setting Value
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE  
['email']
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER   
False
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'en-us'
ROOT_URLCONF    
'app.urls'
MANAGERS    
()
TEMPLATE_LOADERS    
('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')
BASE_DIR    
'/home/useruseruser/diaper'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  
[]
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
SESSION_SERIALIZER  
'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
STATIC_ROOT 
'/var/www/static/xyzzyxsford/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME  
'socialauth_associate_complete'
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
[]
SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_IS_FULL_EMAIL  
True
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
'[Django] '
SERVER_EMAIL    
'root@localhost'
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS 
0
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
('django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder')
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID 
'317469704605-prruuiq0r1b7orr856i3u06a6eikl5kl.apps.googleusercontent.com'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M')
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  
[]
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
             'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
             'NAME': 'hb_dev',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': u'********************',
             'PORT': '5432',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC',
             'USER': 'hartford'}}
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   
u'********************'
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   
None
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
('django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler')
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/html'
APPEND_SLASH    
True
LOCALE_PATHS    
()
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
''
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
'F Y'
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF 
False
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES  
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')
USE_I18N    
True
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
','
SECRET_KEY  
u'********************'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
''
LOGGING_CONFIG  
'logging.config.dictConfig'
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET 
u'********************'
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
WSGI_APPLICATION    
'app.wsgi.application'
TEMPLATE_DEBUG  
False
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
'SAMEORIGIN'
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
None
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
True
EMAIL_TIMEOUT   
None
SECURE_SSL_HOST 
None
SIGNING_BACKEND 
'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
BASE_URL    
'http://linode.useruseruserski.net/dev-xyzzyxsford/'
BASE_PATH   
'/home/useruseruser/diaper/app'
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
URLPREFIX   
'dev-xyzzyxsford/'
FILE_CHARSET    
'utf-8'
DEBUG   
True
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
INSTALLED_APPS  
('rest_framework',
 'p',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'social_auth')
LANGUAGES   
(('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('ast', 'Asturian'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('io', 'Ido'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('mr', 'Marathi'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmal'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-cn', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese'),
 ('zh-tw', 'Traditional Chinese'))
USE_L10N    
True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  
False
STATICFILES_DIRS    
('/home/useruseruser/diaper/static',)
PREPEND_WWW 
False
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE 
None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
FACEBOOK_APP_ID 
'748xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6'
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE 
31449600
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
'F j'
LOGIN_URL   
'/dev-xyzzyxsford/'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS   
{'fields': 'email', 'locale': 'en_US'}
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'auth.User'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y')
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
('social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
 'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2Backend',
 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
u'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
u'********************'
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/dev-xyzzyxsford/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE    
('social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
 'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
 'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
 'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
 'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
 'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
 'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
 'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
 'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
 'social.pipeline.user.user_details')
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
'.'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
()
MIGRATION_MODULES   
{}
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID  
''
LOGOUT_URL  
'/accounts/logout/'
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
False
FIXTURE_DIRS    
()
EMAIL_HOST  
'localhost'
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET 
u'********************'
MEDIA_ROOT  
''
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
ADMINS  
()
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
'webmaster@localhost'
REST_FRAMEWORK  
{'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ['rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly']}
MEDIA_URL   
''
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
TEMPLATE_DIRS   
()
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
()
ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS   
()
LOGGING 
{}
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y'
TEMPLATES   
[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': [],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                                     'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_name_backends',
                                     'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_backends',
                                     'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends',
                                     'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_login_redirect']}}]
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
u'********************'
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT 
False
TIME_ZONE   
'UTC'
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
EMAIL_BACKEND   
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_SSL   
False
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS 
('django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
 'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
 'django.template.context_processors.media',
 'django.template.context_processors.static',
 'django.template.context_processors.tz',
 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages')
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
1209600
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'app.settings'
USE_ETAGS   
False
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
('he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur')
SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME   
'socialauth_complete'
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
INTERNAL_IPS    
()
STATIC_URL  
'/static/xyzzyxsford/'
EMAIL_PORT  
25
USE_TZ  
True
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y P'
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    
[]
PASSWORD_HASHERS    
u'********************'
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  
None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y')
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
''
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard page generated by the handler for this status code.
```

Comment: are you using python social auth or the "deceased" django social auth?

Comment: `python-social-auth==0.2.13`

Comment: I'm not sure it's your problem, but from PSA's docs, it should be added to  `INSTALLED_APPS` as `'social.apps.django_app.default'`, not `'social_auth'`. And then the backend for facebook on `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` would be `'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2'` instead of `'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend'`. Btw, that's how it's in my app and works perfectly, and my pipeline is almost the same as yours except one less function in the end and a few custom ones.

Comment: I get an invalid backend if I use FacebookOAuth2

Comment: To use that you'd need to change `social_auth` in the beginning to `social` too. Maybe change the installed_apps thing too. You can check here in their github that social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2 exists: https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/tree/master/social/backends

Comment: Yeah, turns out I had a bastardized install with both Django social auth and python social auth.  I removed the django one (the old deprecated one) and fixed all the errors and it works.